# How to display strike through text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to display some text with strike through in HTML using xsl.

```
 <xsl:text>Hello world</xsl:text>
```

Expected output: <strike>Hello world</strike>

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't test either of these at the moment, but maybe:

```
<strike><xsl:text>Hello world</xsl:text></strike>
```

or

```
<fo:inline text-decoration="line-through"><xsl:text>Hello world</xsl:Text></fo:inline>
```

Hope one of those works for you!

Comment: with minor modification strike worked. <strike><xsl:text>Hello world</xsl:text></strike> Thanks a lot.